# header location unable to redirect

Tags: php, redirect

**Overview:**

I am having a block of code where I am checking for a condition and redirect to a page(`manage_contents.php`) if the condition(`mysqli_num_rows($pages_set)>0`) satisfies and thus everything after the if condition should not execute as the header has been redirected.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($pages_set)>0) {
    $_SESSION["message"] = "can't delete a subject with pages";
    redirect_to("manage_contents.php?subject={$current_subject["id"]}");    
}

    $id = $current_subject["id"];

    //Standard delete query
    $query = "DELETE FROM subjects WHERE id = {$id} LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    if($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection)==1) {
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Subjects deleted";
        redirect_to("manage_contents.php");
    }else{
        $_SESSION["message"]="Subject deletion failed";
        redirect_to("manage_contents.php?subject={$id}");   
    }
```

But if I execute the above the code isn't redirecting(even if the if condition satisfied) and executing whatever is next to the if loop.

**redirect_to function:**

```
function redirect_to($new_location) {
        header("Location:".$new_location);  
    }
```

Working solution for me:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($pages_set)>0) {
        $_SESSION["message"] = "can't delete a subject with pages";
        redirect_to("manage_contents.php?subject={$current_subject["id"]}");    
    } else {

        $id = $current_subject["id"];

        //Standard delete query
        $query = "DELETE FROM subjects WHERE id = {$id} LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        if($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection)==1) {
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Subjects deleted";
            redirect_to("manage_contents.php");
        }else{
            $_SESSION["message"]="Subject deletion failed";
            redirect_to("manage_contents.php?subject={$id}");   
        }
}
```

So,if i put all the code inside of the else statement then ofcourse it doesn't go to the else section when the if condition satisfies and hence works just fine.

**Doubt:**

Why the header doesn't redirect if I just leave the code outside of else section and why does it redirect just fine when the code is inside of else block?

I think both the code should work exactly same as far I know about header redirects.(when header is redirected all the following codes execution should skip).

Comment: die after header() ?

Comment: Try using `die` or `exit` after header

Comment: yes that will work..but my doubt here is why it is not stopping the script there? I think whenever header location is encountered it must redirect and should not execute any codes following it.

Comment: Why works so hard? Just use a framework like Symfony.

Comment: Why do you think that? What documentation backs up your assertion? From PHP's perspective you could be setting an `X-Foobar` header or a `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the `Location` header is not going to stop processing of the current PHP page. You'll need to explicitly [`exit`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php):

```
function redirect_to($new_location)
{
    header("Location: $new_location");
    exit;
}
```

In other languages/frameworks (ASP.NET's `Response.Redirect` comes to mind) the current page's execution is stopped for you, but this does not happen in PHP and nothing in [the documentation for `header`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) indicates otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the caveat in http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php : when you use the "Location" header you must take care that the code below it will not be executed (and your second code comply with it).